# How to use sharepoint in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint site containing a group of people. In my WPF application I am required to use the sharepoint group information for authentication. How do I get started on using Sharepoint class (if any) in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to accomplish, you may want to start by grabbing the dlls `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and 
`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll` from one of the SharePoint servers, in:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI
```

These will allow you to connect to a SharePoint farm by using the Client Object Model (CSOM).

More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff630937%28v=office.14%29.aspx)